# How to identify visual studio symbols?

Tags: visual-studio, user-interface, symbols

I'm new to the use of MVS, I'm used with the symbols in Eclipse since I programm java already. My question is, where can I find a guideline to identify which code the IDE is suggesting?

[image]

For example: BlendAdd has a white symbol that I dont know what does that means (if its a member function, data or whatever)..To blend mode there is another symbol, for Circle shape another and so on.

In eclipse I know the difference just looking what is a method or a constant. This is a completely beginner question but since yesterday I didn't find anything to clearfy my mind cos maybe I'm searching for the wrong concept.

Thanks in advance for the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a page on MSDN that explains all of it, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

[image] - constant
[image] - enum
[image] - class